# WooCommerce: add different order item meta for each item in order

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

now with this function i can add new custom order item meta to all item of order.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', 'add_order_item_meta', 10, 2 );
function add_order_item_meta($item_id, $values) {
    $key = '_key'; 
    $value = '_value'; 
    wc_update_order_item_meta($item_id, $key, $value);
}
```

but how can i add different order item meta to each item of order? example i need to add each product price as order_itemmeta.

Answer (score 4):

Try,
`woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item` It has 4 available arguments and available after version WooCommerce 3.3+.

- **`$item`** is an instance of `WC_Order_Item_Product` new introduced Class
- **`$cart_item_key`** is the cart item unique hash key
- **`$values`** is the cart item
- **`$order`** an instance of the `WC_Order` object (This is a very useful additional argument in some specific cases)

In this hook we will replace the old working functions `wc_add_order_item_meta()` by the new `WC_Data update_meta_data()` method to be used with `$item` argument.

Example:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'custom_checkout_create_order_line_item', 20, 4 );
function custom_checkout_create_order_line_item( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    // Get a product custom field value
    $custom_field_value = get_post_meta( $item->get_product_id(), '_meta_key', true );
    // Update order item meta
    if ( ! empty( $custom_field_value ) ){
        $item->update_meta_data( 'meta_key1', $custom_field_value );
    }
    // … … Or … …

    // Get cart item custom data and update order item meta
    if( isset( $values['custom_data'] ) ) {
        $item->update_meta_data( 'meta_key2', $values['custom_data'] );
    }
}
```